# Check Directory for new files in android

Tags: android, file, directory

I need to read all files in a directory every say 5 minutes and check if any new files have been created.

What would be the best way to do this?

I thought of using a DB to store all file names and then compare one by one but it seems like it would take too long.

I also thought of writing the file names to a text file and the looking if the file name is on the list or not.

Is there a better way?

Comment: These do involve persistence storage, I go with database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try with `FileObservers`

```
private final class DirectoryObserver extends FileObserver {

private DirectoryObserver(String path, int mask) {
    super(path, mask);
}

@Override
public void onEvent(int event, String pathString) {
    event &= FileObserver.ALL_EVENTS;
    switch (event) {
        case FileObserver.DELETE_SELF:
            //do stuff
            break;

        case FileObserver.CREATE:
        case FileObserver.DELETE:
            //do stuff
            break;
    }
}
}
```

**Ref**:[FileObserver CREATE or DELETE received only for files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20455423/fileobserver-create-or-delete-received-only-for-files)

Comment: I'll try this later. I need to search all the directories under the parentdirectory.

Comment: Your answer led me to this. If it works it's exactly what I need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448002/android-fileobserver-monitors-only-top-directory