# How can I find android apk installation activity programmatically?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

How can I find android apk installation activity programmatically? I mean given the package name of the apk and I can find the installation activity that install this apk.

thanks.

Comment: Try this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/7471652/3048584

Comment: @android-mantra: Hi thanks for the answer, I have tried that, but it only work if the app has finished installed, but not in the installation process.

Comment: It's totally controlled by the android firmware and can't be recorded by normal app or without rooted devices(My guess).

Comment: @android-mantra: how about the default permission that every package need to have the user to agree before installation process begin? Is there such a thing? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can provide a temporary solution for you which can help you.
Include file observer in your app. This can be found from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17301334/3048584).

Next is kepp the observer to detect only for .apk file open event listener then do what you want when it opens.

Note: This would be help if the user installs from the device.

Comment: Thanks, this can be a temporary solution.